# Is it possible to turn a char code (number) into a char in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Something like:

```
var str = "a";
var code = str.charCodeAt(0);
var str2 = "blah " + charFromCode(code);
alert(str2);    // "blah a"
```

I do not think is possible. But I'm asking just in case it is.

**Edit:** Weird. And I **did** google it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var str2 = "blah " + String.fromCharCode(code)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.fromCharCode(code)` where is code is a unicode value.